# Do CSS functions exist?

Tags: css

I'm not sure what to call this, but basically let's say I have a style that I use a lot,

```
.somepattern{
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:2px solid red;
}
```

but sometime I want to change the `font-size` and the color for `border`. Is it possible to treat this code as a library, where I can set the style to a div

```
<div class="somepattern">Text</div>
```

but still control the `16px` and `red` like we do with functions?

Comment: CSS has functions, but not the kind you are looking for.

Comment: funny nobody comes up with the expression declaration

Comment: rgb() and url() are the most frequently used css functions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't programatically control CSS from your markup, but you can use one of the many CSS extensions to make CSS work more like a compiled language.

http://lesscss.org/

http://sass-lang.com/

If we wrote your example in LESS, we'd get something like this:

```
.somepattern(@color: red, @size: 16px) {
    font-size:@size;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:2px solid @color;
}
```

And then you could use it in your LESS file like so:

```
.myclass {
    .somepattern(green, 20px);
}
```

Comment: +1 Use one of these. I only used LESS for one project so far, but I never want to do plain CSS again. Of course, you should use them on the server side if possible.

Comment: So this LESS source code must be compiled to CSS before publishing, or is it directly understood by browsers?

Comment: I much prefer LESS, especially in it's new super fast Javascript incarnation. Doing it on the server, is definitely preferable though - just because a library lets us compile code on the client side doesn't mean it's a great idea.

Comment: @Al, your browser cannot directly understand LESS, but you can compile it before publishing (preferred), or compile it on the fly with Javascript using less.js (they have an example on their homepage).

Comment: @Al Kepp: It's not directly understood by browsers. Needs to be pre-formatted on server side or interpreted on client side by Javascript. A better way is of course server side because styles don't really change lots. If your backed is Asp.net you can always use T4 template to convert all *.less files automagically...

Comment: So it would be nice to have something like PHP interpreter for this LESS. I mean transparent interpreter LESS-->CSS like PHP-->HTML. I would assign LESS file extension to this interpreter and it would serve files compiled to CSS to clients. Or does this already exist? I actually don't know what are T4 templates (and yes, I use asp.net).

Comment: @Al Kepp: Check my answer where I also list other CSS precompilers. I think xCSS is aimed at PHP if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Al Kepp: If you don't know what T4 is, check my answer (again) where I link Phil Haack's T4 template for LESS. Red that blog post and you'll understand a lot more. And mind that T4 can be used for other things as well like [`enum` generation](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/generate-enum-of-database-lookup-table.html)

Comment: @ddagradi Just use LESS with Node.js ;)

Comment: @Al Kepp: I can't speak for Asp.net, but in my editing environment, I have my LESS files compiled immediately when I save them and have my site serve the static files only. The lessc binary that's installed has a --watch option, which recompiles watched files as they're saved.

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel: +1 Yep! Simplest solution.

Comment: Robert, thank you very much especially for mentioning T4. I see it is a great tool, and it can do a lot for me. I never heard about it before. +2

Comment: Can this also be used in Stylus?

Comment: Never used Stylus, but it looks like it supports everything you need to use this pattern. I prefer SCSS though :P

Answer (score 18):

I know I'm late to the party but the selected answer IS NOT the right answer since it's deferring it to CSS preprocessors.

To answer the specific question *"Do CSS functions exist?"*, the answer is: Yes.

However, CSS functions work completely different than the OP's concept initially is.

cuixiping's answer seems the most correct answer.

Examples of CSS functions are:

- `url()`
- `attr()`
- `calc()`
- `rotate()`
- `scale()`
- `linear-gradient()`
- `sepia()`
- `grayscale()`
- `translate()`

A detailed, comprehensive list can be found here:

**[CSS functions on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Functions) Updated link 18/9/20**

Comment: Can we create our own functions in CSS?

Comment: Not currently. Maybe in the future in some shape or form. However if that ever happens, CSS will no longer be CSS but a programming language.

Answer (score 6):

Nope. No CSS functionality like you require. At least not directly.

But there are at least two rather generic ways for you to use to accomplish what you need:

### Class combining

You can of course combine as many classes as you like in any element like:

```
<div class="heading run-in">
    Some heading
</div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
```

and you'd have CSS defined as:

```
.heading {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    display: block;
    margin: 1.5em 0 .5em;
}
.run-in {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

### LESS CSS

And there is of course [LESS CSS project](http://lesscss.org/) that lets you define variables (and has other sugars as well) and use them in other classes.

> LESS extends CSS with dynamic behavior such as **variables**, **mixins**, **operations** and **functions**. LESS runs on both the client-side (IE 6+, Webkit, Firefox) and server-side, with Node.js.

If your server platform is .net there's a project [DotLessCSS](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) with a library in .net as well. And there's also [T4 template](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/02/t4-template-for-less-css.aspx) by Phil Haack.

Mind that there are many CSS preprocessors/enhancers like LESS CSS as well:

- [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)
- [xCSS](http://xcss.antpaw.org/)
- [HSS](http://ncannasse.fr/projects/hss)
- [CleverCSS](http://sandbox.pocoo.org/clevercss/)

And probably some others that I didn't mention. Some support nesting CSS3 selectors as well others don't. Some are aimed at particular server-side technology some don't. So choose wisely.

Comment: Please don't define `.red` or `.size16` classes in your example. CSS classes must be semantical, i.e. named by their semantical purpose, not named by implementation. Although I am sure I use it jsut as an example, this one is a really dangerous one, since many beginners will use it literally in their css code.

Comment: @Al Kepp: Thanks for pointing it out. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Even later to the party!

You can now do this with [css custom variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).

In our css using the [var()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var) function:

```
.some-pattern {
    font-size: var(--font-size);
    font-weight: bold;
    border: var(--border);
  }
```

Then in our html defining the custom variables inline:

```
<div
  class="some-pattern"
  style="--border: 3px double red; --font-size: 16px;"
>
  test
</div>
```

Comment: You can also define the custom variables in a separate CSS class. For example `class="some-pattern red"` and `.red { --border: 3px double red }`

Answer (score 1):

you can redefine style by adding the style tag to your HTML:

```
<div class="somepattern" style="font-size:5px">Text</div>
```

or by applying multiple classes like class="somepattern small".

**HTML**

```
<div class="somepattern small"> Text </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.small {
font-size:5px;
}
```

the `small` class will be applied after the `somepattern` class and will therefore override any properties set in the `some pattern` class.

Comment: +1 but an example of the HTML+CSS would make this answer clearer.

Comment: Inline styles are like creating table of contents in MS Word without using styles... changing CSS ends in unpredictable behaviour of your styles...

Answer (score 0):

What you described is actually done with `style` attribute.

```
<div class="somepattern" style="font-size:10px;">Text</div>
```

I think this is exactly what you want. And it is not recommended, because it breaks the usual (good) pattern of spitting content and its visual style. (Although, honestly, I do use it a lot. ;-))

Comment: I suggest you try not to use inlines at all. I never use them at all. Much happier life. :)

Comment: @Robert: Although you are theoretically right, real world sometimes brings "situations"... Also if you define classes like `.size16` as you suggested in your answer, those are not semantical classes, so they are no way better than to use style attribute directly.

Comment: Oh yes they are. Because changing a single class definition in your CSS file implies predictable results. Having inline styles makes style changes much more complicated. Especially when working in multi-developer teams. My example defined a single CSS setting per class which is of course a very simplified example. Each class definition can be (an usually is) more complex.

Answer (score 0):

its a css class. It cannot be used like functions if that's what you are asking. There is no code library as its not a compiled. CSS is just presentation semantics (formatting) of a document written in a markup language. You can include all css classes in a .css file and use it where ever you want instead.

Answer (score 0):

**I've come to realize through the comments of others that this solution overcomplicates the problem at hand. This solution works but there are easier and better alternatives that do not depend on server-side scripting.**

You can actually control your stylesheet if you make it a php file `stylesheet.php?fontsize=16` and then inside your stylesheet you can retrieve the variable

```
  <?php
     header("Content-type: text/css");
     $fontsize=16;
  ?>

 .somepattern{
   font-size: $fontsize;
   font-weight:bold;
   border:2px solid red;
   }
```

Comment: -1 This is a freaky, freaky solution that's a) dependent on a server-side library and b) veering wildly away from web standards. I'd be really wary of doing stuff like this.

Comment: @ddagradi I've seen this done on numerous sites. Could you please elaborate the dangerous of this method- thanks in advance.

Comment: @Flying Swissman: Complexity maybe? CSS files tend to be quite complex so you'd either end up having lots of simple CSS files or one really complex and you'd have to define lots and lots of variables when referring to it.

Comment: There's no need to use PHP-as-CSS given the numerous solutions put forward by the community independent of server side languages, and using get parameters to manage your styles seems super kludgey. If you really can't get by without manipulating your styles on the fly, use Javascript to add additional CSS classes/inline styles to your elements.

Comment: @Fyling Swissman: Actually thinking of it again I should point out that using this kind of CSS file referencing is much like inline styling. True it's not set on a per-element basis but per-file. Still needs to be changed multiple times to consistently change the look of all targeted pages. Having a lot of variables with different values makes this process even more erroneous.

Comment: Even LESS or SASS has to be compiled server side (client side JavaScript compilers aren't a good solution). Weather you use PHP or any kind of precompiler, you should always serve a compiled (cached) version and only update on change. The main reason why the comments here are negative, that you'll destroy the static file serving standards and eat up more resources. Cache solves this problem, so i don't think PHP is a bad solution but rather use LESS or SASS with NodeJS for compiling...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. But you have to make it on your own with the help of Recatjs(u don't have to go deeper, basic is enough for this). Actually, think like that If bootstrap can make such things where we just have to define the class name and it automatically designes HTML files, then why we cannot do it.

Here's the image of my code(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyePO.png)

and this is how I used it in my jsx code (https://i.stack.imgur.com/yK6VD.jpg)

Comment: Hello. I have edited your answer to remove the personal information, please do not post such things or ask for messaging. The questions *and answers* must happen on the site itself. Also, you should post your code *as formatted text* instead of images. Thank you. :)

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean inline styles ? `<div class="somepattern" style="border-color:green">Text</div>`