# can I write a loop for css

Tags: css

I have a scenario where I am getting ID generated like this

```
<div class="containerLength">
<div id="new-1"></div>
<div id="new-2"></div>
<div id="new-3"></div>
<div id="new-4"></div>
</div>
```

and so on

is there a way I could write some css to target them through a loop?
maybe something like

```
#new[i; for(i=0; i<="containerLength.length"; i++)]{
float:left;
}
```

Probably I am day dreaming correct?

Comment: With plain vanilla CSS no. Why not assign a class to those elements instead? You could however try `div.containerLength > div {...}`

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914533/do-css-functions-exist ?

Comment: `div.containerLength div[id^="new"] { float: left; }`? What is it you're trying to do to these elements, once found/'looped'?

Comment: ...or `.containerLength div:nth-child()` ?

Comment: You can possibly achieve most of your needs by changing your style and using some relatively new selectors like 'nth-child()'

Comment: CSS is not procedural. You can target .containerLength > div {float:left;}, but there is nothing as a loop there

Comment: Thinking about looping CSS is fundamentally misunderstanding how CSS works.

Comment: You shouldnt even want to do this. Separate presentation from logic.

Comment: @Alex It sounds like the OP doesn't have a choice, the markup is dynamically generated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't do loops with pure CSS, however, if you're using something like SASS or LESS then you can do both like:

**SASS**:

```
@for $i from 1 through 4
  .#{$class-slug}-#{$i}
    width: 60px + $i
```

**LESS**:

[Can you do a javascript for loop inside of LESS css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226347/can-you-do-a-javascript-for-loop-inside-of-less-css)

However, assuming you just want to apply the same style to each nested `div`, you can just do

```
.containerLength > div{
  float: left;
}
```

or perhaps create a class named `.float-left` and apply it to each element you want floated right.

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
div.containerLength > div { /* > Matches only first level children of the wrapper div */
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: You don't really need the initial 'div', '.containerLength > div' is enough.

Comment: @facildelembrar I normally like keeping things more explicit. I agree that it is not required.

Comment: With CSS, it's better to be too specific than not specific enough. Only select exactly what you want to change, and nothing more. I can't tell you how many work hours I've spent fixing bad CSS selectors.

Comment: I used to agree with you guys and use a tag selector along with a class selector. What made me change my mind was performance, and to a lesser extent, file size. Check your pages with yslow and pagespeed.

Answer (score 4):

```
div[id|="new"]{
    float: left;
}
```

[documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors)

You may or may not need the quotes, it's weird sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

you can't write any logic at all in css.  you can, however, managed css with JavaScript, or include multiple id's in one rule, or just use a class.

You also may be able to use Css attribute selectors, depending on how the ids are arranged and how broad you need your browser support to be.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Thanks guys. This was really great. Thaks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this:

```
.containerLength > div {float:left}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to think "component"-like with CSS, so the best native way is to have a mutual class and assign styles to it.

```html
<div class="containerLength">
    <div id="common new-1"></div>
    <div id="common new-2"></div>
    <div id="common new-3"></div>
    <div id="common new-4"></div>
</div>

<style>
.common {
    float:left;
}
</style>
```