# add different animation delays for dynamically generated HTML tags

Tags: css, css-animations

I have an HTML page which can generate any number of `<div></div>` tags.

I want to add different animation delays to each `div`, for example :

For an HTML structure :

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

the CSS is

```
div:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 3s;
}

div:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 4s;
}
```

Now without the help of Javascript, does CSS provide any function that will make it easier to do the same for any random number of `div`?

I'm avoiding jQuery because the performance of `each()` is very poor.

Or are there any pure CSS alternatives to delay animation when the upper bound on the number of generated elements is unknown?

Comment: which language you are working with?

Comment: No, CSS does not have any such functions. You will have to use JS (or a library)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly there is not in plain CSS.

Since you are not looking for a Javascript solution at all, one choice you might like is using a CSS preProcessor like SASS or LESS etc.

**SASS Code**:

```
$selector: div !default

@for $i from 1 through 4
  .#{$selector}:nth-child(#{$i})
    animation-delay: $i + "s"
```

Generated CSS Code:

```
.div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: "1s";
}

.div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: "2s";
}

.div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: "3s";
}

.div:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: "4s";
}
```

See also: [can I write a loop for css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987692/can-i-write-a-loop-for-css)

But if you do not want to generate an unkown amount of CSS rules as stated in the comments below. You could use javascript without jQuerys .each and even without element styles.

**Javascript Code**:

```
// function wrapper for inserting rules in stylesheets
function addCSSRule(sheet, selector, rules, index) {
  if(sheet.insertRule) {
    sheet.insertRule(selector + "{" + rules + "}", index);
  } else {
    sheet.addRule(selector, rules, index);
  }
}

// is dom loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {  
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div"); // get all the divs
    var i = divs.length;
    for (i; i > 0; i--) {
      var selector = "div:nth-child(" + i + ")"; // setup selector
      var rule = "animation-delay: " + i + "s" 
      addCSSRule(document.styleSheets[0], selector, rule); // insert rule in first stylesheet.
    }   
});
```

Here is a codepen example of both soluions: http://codepen.io/Type-Style/pen/PZvJWz

See https://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets for more details.

Comment: But, I guess he isn't provided with the maximum divs limit.

Comment: 1 through **4**, problem is when the upper bound is not known. Secondly, I want to avoid JavaScript as possible

Comment: But, that will drastically increase your css file. Isn't it?

Comment: Don't you think then its better to use JQuery for that then :D

Comment: @UmerJaved jepp would increase the file, but with gzipping it is not that much as you might thing.

Comment: @UmerJaved provided an js alternative, without jQuerys.each

Comment: At these days I had to use `$i#{s}` instead of `$i + "s"` which will not output a string but the correct `2s` without quotes.