# Adapting Video size depending on screen size using less css

Tags: html, css, video, less

I am trying to add a video in the background of my homepage.
Basically I want to avoid having black bands on the side when the browser resolution is different from my video resolution.

To optimize loading time, I want to do it using less css so I am trying to define the value in less like this:

```
@videoHeight: '1080';
@videoWidth: '2048';

@alphaVideo: '1,9';

@winHeight:'$(window).height()';
@winWidth:'$(window).width()';


@alphaWin: @winHeight/@winWidth;



@media only screen and (min-width: @alphaVideo * @winHeight) { 
    #video-background { 
   transform: scale(1.1);
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
   -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
   -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
}
```

But I get the following error in my browser:
OperationError: Operation on an invalid type
in video.less on line null, column 0:

1@videoWidth: '2048';

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Alternative approach using JS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090595/center-fullscreen-background-video/18091239#18091239

Comment: possible duplicate of [create a div square, and center it accordingly the view port using less](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983241/create-a-div-square-and-center-it-accordingly-the-view-port-using-less)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LESS is a CSS *preprocessor*, which means it is designed to process *before* even being aware of the browser environment. This is absolutely true when LESS is compiled server side (as recommended). You can become aware of the browser itself (such as window sizing) if LESS is compiled client side (not recommended, as it will do the opposite of what you state that you want, "To optimize loading time").

So to summarize: you cannot both optimize loading time and have LESS be aware of the actual browser sizing.

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't solve the compilation error problem.

Comment: @cimmanon: Perhaps. However, in his code he does not even show an "operation" on the quoted strings that you note. The operation is being done one the `@winHeight` and `@winWidth` variables, which possibly have the dual problem of (1) not having the javascript surrounded by back ticks, and (2) if ran server side, is producing no value.

Comment: Thanks, it makes all sense - I'm very new to less css ^^
What would you suggest to optimize loading time for this video? The idea is to show the video only if the window size is close to my video resolution

Comment: @ArnaudDrizard: probably using `@media` queries checking [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FMedia_queries#aspect-ratio) will get what you are seeking, perhaps also with some `min` value for either width or height.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're trying to perform math operations (division, multiplication) on a string.  The only thing LESS can do with strings is concatenate them.  Quoting a variable makes it a string, so don't do it unless you actually want a string:

```
@videoHeight: 1080;
@videoWidth: 2048;
```

Comment: You make a good point as well. The OP probably wanted the back tick marks for inline javascript, rather than single quotes.